# Pyspark sort and get first and last

Tags: pyspark

I used code belopw to sort based on one column. I am wondering how can I get the first element and last element in sorted dataframe?

```
 group_by_dataframe
        .count()
        .filter("`count` >= 10")
        .sort(desc("count"))
```

Comment: there's `pyspark.sql.functions.min` and `pyspark.sql.functions.max` as well as `pyspark.sql.functions.first` and `pyspark.sql.functions.last`. It would be helpful if you could provide a small [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples).

Answer (score 1):

The `max` and `min` functions need to have a group to work with, to circumvent the issue, you can create a `dummy` column as below, then call the `max` and `min` for the maximum and minimum values.

If that's all you need, you don't really need `sort` here.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([("a", 0.694), ("b", -2.669), ("a", 0.245), ("a", 0.1), ("b", 0.3), ("c", 0.3)], ["n", "val"])
df.show()

+---+------+
|  n|   val|
+---+------+
|  a| 0.694|
|  b|-2.669|
|  a| 0.245|
|  a|   0.1|
|  b|   0.3|
|  c|   0.3|
+---+------+


df = df.groupby('n').count() #.sort(F.desc('count'))
df = df.withColumn('dummy', F.lit(1))
df.show()

+---+-----+-----+
|  n|count|dummy|
+---+-----+-----+
|  c|    1|    1|
|  b|    2|    1|
|  a|    3|    1|
+---+-----+-----+


df = df.groupBy('dummy').agg(F.min('count').alias('min'), F.max('count').alias('max')).drop('dummy')
df.show()

+---+---+
|min|max|
+---+---+
|  1|  3|
+---+---+
```